# Open Modal in parent component from child component

Tags: angular

I have a parent component and a child component in an angular project, and I need to open a modal that is placed in parent from child, so I'm using ng-Zorro, if I have a code like it for open the modal in parent component:

Parent:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'nz-demo-modal-basic',
  template: `
    <button nz-button [nzType]="'primary'" (click)="showModal()"><span>Show Modal</span></button>
    <nz-modal [(nzVisible)]="isVisible" nzTitle="The first Modal" (nzOnCancel)="handleCancel()" (nzOnOk)="handleOk()">
      <ng-container *nzModalContent>
        <p>Content one</p>
        <p>Content two</p>
        <p>Content three</p>
      </ng-container>
    </nz-modal>
  `
})
export class NzDemoModalBasicComponent {
  isVisible = false;

  constructor() {}

  showModal(): void {
    this.isVisible = true;
  }

  handleOk(): void {
    console.log('Button ok clicked!');
    this.isVisible = false;
  }

  handleCancel(): void {
    console.log('Button cancel clicked!');
    this.isVisible = false;
  }
}
```

What I should do for open the same modal from child?
Are related @Input and @Output for do it?
Also I want to know it because I don't want to have duplicate code  in de project so also an service can be useful for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think preferred way to implement it is to add `@Output` in a child component that will trigger `showModal` method call in parent.